# Action Cable connection issue on rails 5.0.6

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5, actioncable

I'm following  [rails 5.0 guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/v5.0/action_cable_overview.html) to configure action cable but I'm getting error on action cable connection here are contents of application.js

```
//= require cable
//= require_tree ./cable
```

I am getting following error.

```
WebSocket connection to 'ws://localhost:3000/cable' failed: Error during WebSocket handshake: Unexpected response code: 500
```

but if I add this in development.rb

```
 config.action_cable.url = 'ws://localhost:28080'
```

and I also need to run

```
bundle exec puma -p 28080 cable/config.ru
```

everything starts working. but why I need to todo all these why connection is not establishing on default url.

Comment: Add your route file here

Comment: why you need `//= require cable` and `//= require_tree ./cable` in application.js? check the example again, you can simply do `//= require_tree .`

Comment: `//= require jquery2
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require cable
//= require turbolinks`   try this order